# jQuery AJAX from submit with variable url

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to submit various forms on the same page via jQuery/AJAX, it is for an admin site where you edit users so the url/action for the form gets generated dynamically. e.g

`/user/limit/update?userId=7`

or

`/user/address/update?id=2`.

is there a way find the forms url/action, store it in a variable and pass it the the url in the ajax function?

hopefully the example will make it more obvious.

the generated form tag is

`<form action="/user/update?id=3" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlen" id="idfff">`

and updated ajax from the suggestion is

```
$("#user-submit").click(function() { 
    $.ajax({  
        type: "post",  
        url: $('#idfff').attr('action'),
        data:$('#user-update').serialize(),
        success: function() {
            $("<div class='update-success'>Details updated</div>").insertAfter("#user-submit");
          }
    });
    return false; 
});
```

Hopefully I have explained my problem correctly but please let me know if you require further info.

Thanks

Comment: The handler is generic enough to bind it to all form submits with a class instead of having one handler per form bond to the id. You'd need to change a few things like `$('#limits').serialize(),` to `$(this).parents('form').serialize(),`

Comment: It does the same thing does it not? I'm not fussed about the smaller points at the moment just trying to get the submit to work then I can tidy.

Comment: It actually does. Didn't mean to upset your plan, it was just a suggestion ;)

Comment: Oh I wasn't belittling your contribution it was just a test on 1 form run so I wasn't worried about the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `attr()` function on the form element to get action attribute value. In your example it should be something like this: `url: $('#limits').attr('action')`

Comment: seems so obvious (slaps forehead), as I finished writing the question I kind of new what the answer would be, for some reason I was asking the back end developer to create a play variable and just blanked on the obvious answer. I will test it out and accept when I can. thanks

Comment: it still posts via page refresh and not ajax, I have edited my question to include more info

Comment: You need to call `preventDefault()` to cancel normal post back, check this [article](http://jqapi.com/#p=event.preventDefault)

Comment: Thanks for your help, turns out the back end developer added another submit button with the same id, after I added your original suggestion it still wasn't working but got it now...

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following?

```
$("#yourForm").attr("action");
```